# Why does GoDaddy have four different certificate chain, G2, G3, G4?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

I see from Godaddy they have multiple certificate chains https://certs.godaddy.com/repository

- GoDaddy Certificate Chain
- GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G2
- GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G3
- GoDaddy Certificate Chain - G4

What is the purpose of each and what do the G2, G3 and G4 stand for?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"G" stands for Root certificates generation. Basically, it identifies the generation (version) of a Root certificate that signs the Chain of trust. When CA needs to get a new chain (for example, because of upgrade from SHA-1 to SHA-256), they just increment the generation number. This is good because obsolete certificates can be better identified.

Comment: I believe you, but your answer would be a lot better if you could provide a citation.